# "Had...been" or "Was...been," and "would have" or "would had"?

Tags: grammar, tense, structure

I want to say, if some person was told about the situation before, she wouldn't have reacted that way.

So which one seems grammatically correct?

> **Had** Ishaani known about the situation before, she wouldn't have felt so heartbroken.

or:

> **Was** Ishaani been informed before, she wouldn't have felt so heartbroken.

Or should that last one be:

> **Was** Ishaani been informed before, she wouldn't **had** felt so heartbroken.

Or any other sentence form would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the context makes clear what the missing information was, then you could simply say:

> Had Ishaani known, she wouldn't have felt so heartbroken.

Answer (score 0):

> "Had Ishaani known about the situation before, she wouldn't have felt so heart broken"

Works (slight modification, "wouldn't" has an apostrophe, it's a conjunction of "would" and "not")

> "was Inshani been informed before, She wouldn't have felt so heart broken.

Doesn't really work, and will likely confuse who hears it. "Was [noun] been" is not a pattern generally used in English. The following

The following also work:

> "If Inshani had been informed before, She wouldn't have had felt so heart broken.

or

> "Had Inshani been informed, she wouldn't have been heartbroken."

For this last one, "before" isn't needed, since informed, had, and been are all past tense, implying it as a before event. Further, since heartbroken is exclusively a feeling, saying she felt it is a little redundant.

or

> "Inshani wouldn't have been heartbroken if she had known."

This one technically flows as one thought instead of a first thought and following thought

Answer (score 0):

You can say *had X {past-participle}* as part of a question that uses past perfect.

> Had I gone to the park ..., had I walked to the store ...

and *was X {past-participle}* as part of a question that uses passive voice...

> Was the dog walked by someone today?  Was I informed by someone of X ...

but {form of be} + {past-participle} + {another past-participle} doesn't ever work.

> Was I been informed ... [bad]

It *does* work with *have*.  This is past perfect + passive voice in question form.

> Have I been informed (ok)